# Can't run android emulator in titanium

Tags: android, emulation, titanium

I've had so much trouble running the Android emulator for titanium studio. I've installed the sdk. I've installed the tools/platforms, and can even run the virtual device from the path/to/android/tools/android SDK and ADM Manager.

I would think that it was a problem with the SDK install, but when I create a project and specify the android path, I'm able to pick a platform and create my project. However, I can't see the Run Emulator option for anything.

All I see is "Run Configurations..". When I go into that, I see "Titanium Android Emulator", but when I click on the configuration and set some options, it won't let me browse for a project. At the top it just says "Project should be selected.".

If there's any console info I can provide that might help, I'm willing to get. I'm just so frustrated that I can't get this working!

I'm on OSX 10.6.8

**# javac -version**

javac 1.6.0_26

**# java -version**

java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode

is it because it's not using JDK? or is it? Any help would be great?

EDIT 1:

EDIT 1:

I opened the Console and tried clicking on the browse button just to see if it'd spit something out. this was spit out in the log?

10/16/11 11:16:50 AM    [0x0-0x27027].com.appcelerator.titanium[730]    !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception

10/16/11 11:16:50 AM    [0x0-0x27027].com.appcelerator.titanium[730]    !STACK 0

10/16/11 11:16:50 AM    [0x0-0x27027].com.appcelerator.titanium[730]    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ProjectSelectionDialog_Title

10/16/11 11:16:50 AM    [0x0-0x27027].com.appcelerator.titanium[730]        at

com.aptana.ui.dialogs.ProjectSelectionDialog.(ProjectSelectionDialog.java:36)

10/16/11 11:16:50 AM    [0x0-0x27027].com.appcelerator.titanium[730]        at

com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.BaseTitaniumLaunchConfigurationTab.browseProject(BaseTitaniumLaunchConfigurationTab.java:178)

10/16/11 11:16:50 AM    [0x0-0x27027].com.appcelerator.titanium[730]        at

com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.BaseTitaniumLaunchConfigurationTab.access$0(BaseTitaniumLaunchConfigurationTab.java:176)

10/16/11 11:16:50 AM    [0x0-0x27027].com.appcelerator.titanium[730]        at

com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.BaseTitaniumLaunchConfigurationTab$1.widgetSelected(BaseTitaniumLaunchConfigurationTab.java:63)

so.. uh. any ideas? Re-install?

Comment: Have you tried selecting a project (click on the project in the Project Explorer view) and _then_ clicking `Run Configurations...`?

Comment: Just tried doing that (sorry for the late response) as well as right-clicking on the project and doing it that way. It just won't open a dialog or anything when I click the browse button.

Comment: Weird. Your Eclipse install (or one of the plugins) might be hosed. Try starting Eclipse with `-clean`, or reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,
1. Open Titanium Application.
2. After open Titanium. Firstly open a Dashboard Window. 
3. Here you select Configure Tab,
4. Click on Let's go thing Setup!
5. After this You select Android.
6. in Right Side select Update Android SDK.

I think this is helpful to you ...
cheers...!